# Unexpectedly Found Nil in UIView.transition

Tags: ios, swift

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    images = ["gambar1", "gambar2", "gambar3", "gambar4"]
    home?.image = UIImage.init(named: "gambar1")
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 2.0, target: self, selector: #selector(onTransition), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

@objc func onTransition() {
    if (photoCount < images.count - 1){
        photoCount = photoCount  + 1;
    }else{
        photoCount = 0;
    }
    UIView.transition(with: self.home, duration: 1, options: .transitionCrossDissolve, animations: {
        self.home.image = UIImage.init(named: self.images[self.photoCount])
    }, completion: nil)
}
```

**NOTE :**

> Unexpetedly found nil while unwarpping an Optional value in line,
>   below :

```
**UIView.transition(with: self.home, duration: 1, options: .transitionCrossDissolve, animations: {**
```

Can somebody please tell me what's going on? Thank you

Comment: Show the declaration for the home variable and its assignment.

Comment: Is `self.images[self.photoCount]` contains image?

Comment: Check if `self.home` is nil or not as you used `home?.image` at one place and `self.home.image` on rest of the places

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transition methode only accept wrapped variable but `self.home` is optional here, so put `if-let` to check:

```
UIView.transition(with: self.home, duration: 1, options: .transitionCrossDissolve, animations: {
    self.home.image = UIImage.init(named: self.images[self.photoCount])
}, completion: nil)
```

> If your image view `home` is an `IBOutlet` then check whether you have correctly connected it from storyboard.
>
> If your image view `home` is created from code, check if it has been initialised and have a proper value.

```
if let view = self.home {
    UIView.transition(with: view, duration: 1, options: .transitionCrossDissolve, animations: {
        view.image = UIImage.init(named: self.images[self.photoCount])
    }, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: if self.home was optional then compiler will immediately throw error so if-let is not an issue.

Comment: @Cordova used `home?.image` in `viewDidAppear`.. It might be a case.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I followed your instructions and it works :)